# Laravel - browser says my js function is not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

Here is my script from main page

```
<script>
gal_size = {} ;

function add_nr(w,nr){
    gal_size[w] = nr;
}
console.log(gal_size);
function edit_addgal(w) {
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    node.setAttribute('class','row');
    node.setAttribute('id',w+'sec'+gal_size[w]);
    node.innerHTML ="<div style='padding-top: 15px;' class='offset-4 col-md-6'><input type='file' min='0' class='form-control' name="+"'sec"+ gal_size[w]+"' required autocomplete='photo'></div>";
    document.getElementById("edit_gale"+w).appendChild(node);
    gal_size[w] =   gal_size[w] + 1;
}

function edit_delgal(w) {
    var node = document.getElementById(w+'sec'+( gal_size[w] - 1));
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    gal_size[w] =  gal_size[w] - 1;
}
```

and i want t pass some variables in @include another page
and this is the script

```
 <script>
        add_nr({!! $wid[1] !!},{!! $nr !!});
</script>
```

browser says its undefined even though the ide sees it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please explain a bit where you had defined your function ?
else what i thought is you have defined your function in main blade file in footer 
and called in that includes . 
the function is called before it loads footer of main page so it gets undefined
please put your function in header then check if its returning undefined or not

Comment: Mybee your @ include came after the second script ? So the browser still dont know it ?

Comment: on click if that works means its not loaded when function is called . So please write it in separate JS file and include that in head section of main layout . Then call it as above

Comment: it worked to load it form the  head tag, you can put your solution so I can upvote you @FaisalMehmoodAwan